# Copy base class reference value to map with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, dictionary, reference, shared-ptr

I have a base class and derived class (BaseObj and Derived Obj) and I need to have a map of string keys that would have pointers to the objects:

```
std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<BaseObj>
```

Here is the complication: the map values need to be on the heap as the objects will go out of scope, however the objects are passed by reference to the function:

```
void insert_in_map(std::string, const& BaseObj);
```

Since the reference is to the base class, there is no way (to my knowledge) of copying the underlying value to the heap and getting a base pointer to it. The only solution I can think of is to change the function prototype to accept a shared_ptr that has already allocated the object on the heap. However, I really would like to avoid creating the shared_ptr in all the callers, especially since the shared_ptr has to be copied into the map.

Any ideas?

Comment: "However, I really would like to avoid creating the shared_ptr in all the callers, especially since the shared_ptr has to be copied into the map." Your reasoning is bogus, especially since shared_ptr suppose to be inserted into map you should change function signature. But it is not clear why you need shared_ptr. unique_ptr should be sufficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any ideas?

Yes, you should change your function signature to:

```
void insert_in_map(std::string, std::unique_ptr<BaseObj>);
```

so this will clearly show that function takes ownership of the object. Your map probably also should be changed to have `std::unique_ptr` instead of shared one, unless you really need shared ownership. In that case you can change them both to `std::shared_ptr` (which could be little bit more effective than converting `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr` inside function). I would create type alias and use it in the both cases.

> However, I really would like to avoid creating the shared_ptr in all the callers, especially since the shared_ptr has to be copied into the map.

It does not have to be copied, it can be moved into the map, so your reasoning is strange - you should not take ownership of an object, passed by const reference.

If you cannot change function signature, you could add virtual method `std::shared_ptr<BaseObject> clone()` into base class and override accordingly. But that seems to be unreasonable in your case, since you can change function signature, you do not want by some strange reasons.

Comment: Is it possible to pass a unique_ptr to a function by value since that would result in two unique_ptrs pointing to the same address?

Comment: Also, my reasoning for using a shared_ptr is that the pointer needs to be retrieved from the map later without deleting the record from the map. So this needs a shared_ptr as I believe a unique_ptr cannot exist in two places and map to the same address.

Comment: Yes it is possible to pass by value, and such way I suggested. Alternative could be to pass by rvalue reference.

Comment: If you need to have shared ownership yes that would be reasonable, just remember that it has price, so it should be used only when necessary. `std::unique_ptr` is more lightweight.